# What objects do I use to communicate with server in a simple game?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm building a simple game, what objects do I use in order to communicate with server? Not the dynamic part (like moving characters), but stuffs like change name, buy items... I've see so many types `RemoteObject`, `URLLoader`, `URLRequest`, `HTTPService` I dont know what to use.

PS: I need to setup the header of the communication.

Comment: For all intents and purposes it doesn't matter. What types does your server accept?  My impulse is that using RemoteObject w/ AMF will give you better performance than using JSON or XML w/ HTTPService or SOAP/XML w/ WebService.

Comment: In my experience, RemoteObject + amf + php is fast and easy way to develop simple game, And socket for more complicated game(as you said, charaters moving, many notifications）.